# Why is UIImage from imageWithCGImage breaking in arm64?

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimage, arm64

Below is some code that converts a UIImage to a CGImage, makes some changes to the CGImage, then converts it back to a UIImage.

This works if my architectures include arm6 and arm7 only. If I add arm64, the UIImage returned at the end is null.

There are some hard coded numbers in the code, which makes me think that is the problem. But I am not sure how to programmatically determine these values.

Here's the code, minus some details in the middle:

```
    CGImageRef imageRef = [anImage CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Raw data malloc'd
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context =
        CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                              bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);        
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

...
// Change the alpha or color of pixels based on certain criteria
...

    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);        
    free(rawData);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    CFRelease(ref);
```

Any thoughts on what's happening here?

Comment: If you assign the `CGImage` to a layer's `content` property, does it display? If it doesn't, then your `CGImage` is probably messed up to begin with, which might have something to do with the block of code that you've commented out where you've modified pixels directly.

Comment: I am not very familiar with working directly with layers. But your comment did lead me to actually remove all of the inner code. Now, when I run only the above code, I get the same nil image. In other words, I convert a UIImage to a CGImageRef. Then that untouched CGImageRef to a UIImage, and the UIImage is nil.